# Erro em membro estático em implementação de Singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

Ao implementar o padrão Singleton o compilador dá o seguinte erro:

> include\graphdata.h|21|error: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 'graphdata* graphdata::instance' of non-integral type [-fpermissive]|

O código que eu fiz é o seguinte:

```
class graphdata
{
    public:
        static graphdata& getinstance(){
            if(!instance)
                instance = new graphdata();
            return *instance;
        }
        void dfsR();
        graphdata(graphdata const&) = delete;
        void operator = (graphdata const&) = delete;
    protected:

    private:
        graphdata();
        static graphdata* instance = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

É exatamente o que está escrito, se deseja inicializar um valor na declaração da classe precisa ser uma expressão constante (`constexpr`). Se não pode ser constante deve inicializar no construtor estático ou no seu código normal antes de usar a variável.

Comment: eu até tentei, mas ficada dando erro falando que *instance é privado.

Comment: Aí é outro erro, eu te mostrei como resolver este erro. Mas sugiro começar fazer coisas mais simples antes. Está patinando em pontos básicos que deve aprender antes de tentar fazer algo mais complexo.